# Could anyone tell me why the action of the hover does not work in append boxes?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, append

I'm trying to do something simple, but I bumped into this problem.

When I insert new boxes through the button, the action of the hover does not work in append boxes.

here's an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UDwc/)

```
$("#insert").click(function() {

  $("body").append('<div class="box"><div class="inside-box"></div></div>');

});
```

Comment: Dynamic elements do not exist when the code of hover filters the elements on the page. You need to use event delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single word : [Delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Now, after reading the above link, you'll see that to use event delegation, you need to use `.on` with a selector parameters.

`hover` is not an event itself, it is a shortcut for `.mouseenter/.mouseleave`. By combining those 2 events, you can recreate a delegated `hover` :

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter : function () {
        //over

        $(this).find(".inside-box").animate({height: '70px'},"fast" ); 
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //out

        $(this).find(".inside-box").animate({height: '10px'},"fast" ); 
    }
}, '.box');
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2UDwc/5/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this through CSS instead:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UDwc/3/)**

```
#insert{
   float:left;
   width:99%;
   padding:7px;
   background:#093;
   text-align:center;
   margin-bottom:10px;
   cursor:pointer;
}

.box{
    position:relative;
    width:250px;
    height:150px;
    background:#09F;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

/*Added this code*/
.box:hover .inside-box{
    height:70px;
}

.inside-box{
   transition:.3s;              /*Added this line*/
   -webkit-transition:.3s;      /*Added this line*/
   -moz-transition:.3s;         /*Added this line*/
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   height:10px;
   background:#000;
   bottom:0;
}
```

The benefits of this is that there is less code to write, easier to understand and better performances.

Disadvantages are that it only works in [IE10 and above](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions). All other browsers work fine though (chrome, opera, safari etc).

Comment: The disadvantage of course is cross-browser compatibility (IE 10+ only) http://caniuse.com/css-transitions.

Comment: It was meant to be a joke... @TrueBlueAussie My bad, will just give a 'proper' answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code which sets up the hover only runs against the boxes that exist at that time, if you add more boxes later they don't magically have event handlers set - you will need to do this yourself.

Try putting the 'hover' code into a function (eg `setupHover`) and applying this to each new box as you create it.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic elements do not exist when the code of hover filters the elements on the page. You need to use event delegation.

Unfortunately `hover` is not an event that is available to event delegation (as it requires two callback functions), so use `on` with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2UDwc/4/

```
$("#insert").click(function () {
    $("body").append('<div class="box"><div class="inside-box"></div></div>');
});

$(document).on('mouseenter', ".box", function () {
    //over
    $(this).find(".inside-box").animate({
        height: '70px'
    }, "fast");
}).on('mouseleave', '.box', function () {
    //out
    $(this).find(".inside-box").animate({
        height: '10px'
    }, "fast");
});
```